# Variable not updating in print statement

Tags: python, function

Hi im pretty new to programming and was working on making a game of tic tac toe
The idea for a board was creating a print statement with variables that could be updated depending on the position you want to play ex:

```
a1 = " "
a2 = " "
a3 = " "
b1 = " "
b2 = " "
b3 = " "
c1 = " "
c2 = " "
c3 = " "
board = f'''     
       A   B   C 
     _____________
1    | {a1} | {b1} | {c1} |
     -------------
2    | {a2} | {b2} | {c2} |
     -------------
3    | {a3} | {b3} | {c3} |
     -------------'''
```

But while trying to update the variables after a play. The board remains the same. The variables themselves do change doing print(a1) shows this. But the board doesn't does anybody know why this is or how i can fix it.

I've tried moving the variables to before the function tictactoe() is defined. I tried moving them to in the same while True: loop as to where the game is actually being played. I've tried moving them to the beginning of the function (thats where i originally put them). But to no avail the board doesn't change heres the code Im grateful for any advice.

```
def tictactoe():
    ox = 0
    a1 = " "
    a2 = " "
    a3 = " "
    b1 = " "
    b2 = " "
    b3 = " "
    c1 = " "
    c2 = " "
    c3 = " "
    board = f'''     
       A   B   C 
     _____________
1    | {a1} | {b1} | {c1} |
     -------------
2    | {a2} | {b2} | {c2} |
     -------------
3    | {a3} | {b3} | {c3} |
     -------------'''

    tttconsole = input("Welcome to tic tac toe X goes first: [PLAY TO PLAY | EXIT TO EXIT]")
    if tttconsole.lower() == "exit":
        print("exiting")
        return
    if tttconsole.lower() == "play":
        while True:
            playconsole = input("How to play? Input position on grid ex B2 is center. Play is then swapped. First to line of 3 wins")

            if playconsole.lower() == "a1":
                if ox == 0:
                    a1 = "X"
                    ox = 1
                    print(board)
                elif ox == 1:
                    a1 = "O"
                    ox = 0
                    print(board)
tictactoe()
```

Comment: `board` is just a string.  It's not going to magically change later, just because some of the variables that went into creating that string have changed values. You would need to recreate the string every time you want to print the current board state.

Comment: I see so board only uses the variables when it's created. Not everytime its printed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you write :

```
value = [your_value]
string = f"{value}"
```

It will only replace the actual value of your variable in the string; however, it's no longer connected to the dynamic value of your variable.

Furthermore, your function "tictactoe()" isn't the right way to define a function. It stores data, performs various tasks, etc. You need to study the concepts and uses of variables, data structures, functions, objects, and how to properly structure your code.

Nonetheless, one way to make your script functional would be:

```
# better to store your data in a dict
values_of_cells = {"a1" : " ", "a2" : " ", etc etc}  
def construct_board(values_of_cells):
    # Replace in your drawing {a1} with {values_of_cells["a1"]}, and do the same for "a2", etc.
    return [your_drawing_of_the_board]
```

When you need to refresh the screen after the user inputs something, you can do (assuming values_of_cells is accessible):

```
# change the element of the dict
values_of_cells["cell_you_want_to_change"] = "X"
print(construct_board(values_of_cells))
```

While this should work, if you aim to improve your code (and learn in the process), you should think of constructing your data structure and board dynamically rather than storing it in a string and changing some values (with for loops for example). Your code will be much more effective, and you could alter the way you display your board, the number of rows, or any other modifications you'd like.

Hope this helps, and good luck!